# VB.NET disable fade-in for forms

Tags: vb.net, pinvoke

I want to disable the form fade-in effect for a window. 
I think I found the right function

```
<DllImport("dwmapi.dll", PreserveSig:=True)> _
Private Shared Function DwmSetWindowAttribute(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal attr As Integer, ByRef attrValue As Integer, ByVal attrSize As Integer) As Integer
End Function
```

and the flag should be

```
DWMWA_TRANSITIONS_FORCEDISABLED
```

But I don't know how to call it from VB.NET. This is what I have so far:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class Form1

Public Enum DWMWINDOWATTRIBUTE
    DWMWA_ALLOW_NCPAINT = 4
    DWMWA_CAPTION_BUTTON_BOUNDS = 5
    DWMWA_FLIP3D_POLICY = 8
    DWMWA_FORCE_ICONIC_REPRESENTATION = 7
    DWMWA_LAST = 9
    DWMWA_NCRENDERING_ENABLED = 1
    DWMWA_NCRENDERING_POLICY = 2
    DWMWA_NONCLIENT_RTL_LAYOUT = 6
    DWMWA_TRANSITIONS_FORCEDISABLED = 3
End Enum

<DllImport("dwmapi.dll", PreserveSig:=True)> _
Private Shared Function DwmSetWindowAttribute(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal attr As Integer, ByRef attrValue As Integer, ByVal attrSize As Integer) As Integer
End Function

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 6 Then
        DwmSetWindowAttribute Me.Handle, 'here I don't know how to go on...
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for [`DWMWA_TRANSITIONS_FORCEDISABLED`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa969530.aspx) reads:

> Use with DwmSetWindowAttribute. Enables or forcibly disables DWM transitions. The pvAttribute parameter points to a value of TRUE to disable transitions or FALSE to enable transitions.

The macros `TRUE` and `FALSE` are declared as:

```
#define FALSE 0
#define TRUE  1
```

So you need to pass `1` for the `attrValue` parameter.

The boolean type that Windows uses natively is `BOOL`. This is declared like this:

```
typedef int BOOL;
```

And since `sizeof(int)` is `4`, the `attrSize` you need to pass is `4`.

Answer (score 1):

What works for me is

```
    If Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 6 Then
        DwmSetWindowAttribute(Me.Handle, DWMWINDOWATTRIBUTE.DWMWA_TRANSITIONS_FORCEDISABLED, 1, 4)
    End If
```

But that is just a guess. I am not sure if "1" stands for YES, and I am not sure if the length 4 is correct under all conditions.
Having this confirmed would be great.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The function is awkward because of the attribute value argument type.  It uses void*, typical for a C function that accepts different sized values.  This is actually something you can easily deal with in VB.NET, you can write different overloads of the same function with different types for argument.  The compiler then automatically figures out which one to call based on the argument you pass.

Let's focus on the specific attribute you want to change, it is a BOOL value.  So write an overload of the function that takes a Boolean, it is automatically marshaled to BOOL without you having to help:

```
<DllImport("dwmapi.dll")> _
Private Shared Function DwmSetWindowAttribute(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, _
            ByVal attr As Integer, ByRef attrValue As Boolean, _
            ByVal attrSize As Integer) As Integer
End Function
```

Let's simplify the enum, you only need one of them:

```
Private Const DWMWA_TRANSITIONS_FORCEDISABLED As Integer = 3
```

Then you need to change the place where you call this function, a window can be created more than once but the Load event runs only once.  You need to call it right after the window is created.  Adding the error handling so you can diagnose runtime problems:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnHandleCreated(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    MyBase.OnHandleCreated(e)
    If Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 6 Then
        Dim hr = DwmSetWindowAttribute(Me.Handle, _
                    DWMWA_TRANSITIONS_FORCEDISABLED, True, 4)
        If hr < 0 Then Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr)
    End If
End Sub
```

Worked well when I tested it.