# Disable aero animation on opening maximized window visualbasic or c#

Tags: c#, winapi, aero

I want to achieve the same effect as google chrome. (When Google chrome is set to maximized, the aero animation is turned off when opening). Is there a way to do this in visual basic/c#? If not, what part of the windows api is this in?

Comment: possible duplicate of [VB.NET disable fade-in for forms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14001694/vb-net-disable-fade-in-for-forms)